# Apps Script Webapp accessing Google Spreadsheet gets #VALUE! on every cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet with a couple of sheets that get data from other spreadsheets via ImportRange function and then calculate numeric values based on that data.
Then, I assembled a code snippet as web app to retrieve the first sheet of the spreadsheet and  show it as a flex table.

Besides the doGet function, I added a "refresher" to retrieve the data from the spreadsheet, because when the Ss is closed, no calculations are performed, and the script would only read empty cells.

However, even though the "refresher" is in place, it shows only `#VALUE!` where the numbers should display.

I'm not sure where to fix my code, please give me a hint!

Thanks!

---

I'm adding an actual screenshot to further illustrate the issue. The alphanumeric values that appear are "native" to the spreadsheet, and the values that do not, are coming from other spreadsheet via importRange function. The script is placed in the "google site root", not inside the spreadsheet.

[image: Actual screenshot]

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var flexTable = app.createFlexTable().setStyleAttribute('border', '3px solid MidnightBlue')
      .setStyleAttribute('borderCollapse','collapse')
      .setBorderWidth(2);
      //Get Data from spreadsheet
  var spreadsheetId = 'xxxx.xxx.xxxx';
  var dataArray = getData(spreadsheetId);
 //Load data into table cells 
  for (var row = 0; row<dataArray.length; row++){
    for (var col = 0; col<dataArray[row].length; col++){
      flexTable.setText(row, col, dataArray[row][col].toString());
    }
  }  
  panel.add(flexTable);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

function refreshSheet(spreadsheetId, sheet) {
  var spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx');
  var sheet = spreadsheetId.getSheetByName('Sheet_to_Display');
  var dataArrayRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn());
  var dataArray = dataArrayRange.getValues(); // necessary to refresh custom functions
  var notValueFound = true;
  while(notValueFound) {
    for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
      if(dataArray[i].indexOf('#VALUE!') >= 0) {
        notValueFound = true;
        dataArray = dataArrayRange.getValues();
        break;
      } // end if
      else if(i == dataArray.length - 1) notValueFound = false;
    } // end for
  } // end while
}

function getData (spreadsheetId){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange();
  return sheet.getValues();
}
```

Comment: The code seems to be working fine. I added a time-based trigger (1 by the hour) to invoke the `refreshSheet` function, suggested by @JacobJanTuinstra, and it works like charm. However, I may have 300+ versions of this code retrieving data from 300+ spreadsheets inserted in 300+ Google Sites pages, under the same domain in Google Apps, and I believe I might encounter some usage limits. Don't you think? Any ideas?